# Como reproduzir algo dentro do useEffect ReactJS sem virar um loop?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Meus caros, estava fazendo um exemplo que vi na internet onde o client faz a consulta pela api, e o get do `axios` é inserido dentro do useEffect que fica escutando caso haja novo valor no banco e já renderiza na tela. Porém eu queria reproduzir um som a cada novo dado renderizado, mas se eu inserir o play dentro do useEffect ele fica em loop tocando sem parar. A idéia é fazer como uma tela de fila de espera.

Segue abaixo o meu codigo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Card from './components/cards/card';
import { Howl, Howler } from 'howler';
import ring from './assets/audio/ding.mp3';

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState();
  const [listGames, setListGames] = useState();
  const callMySound = () => {
    const sound = new Howl({
      src: [ring],
      html5: true,
    });   
    sound.play();   
  }
  const handleChangeValues = (value) => {
    setValues((prevValue) => ({
      ...prevValue,
      [value.target.name]: value.target.value,
    }));    
  };
  const handleClickButton = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/register", {
      name: values.name,
      cost: values.cost,
      category: values.category
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getCards").then((response) => 
    {
      setListGames(response.data);
      callMySound();      
    });
  });
  return (<div className="app--container">
    <div onClick={() => callMySound()}>Click me to play sound</div>
    <h1 className='meu'></h1>
    <div className="register--container">
      <h1 className="register--title">Scrim Shop</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        placeholder="Nome"
        className="register--input"
        onChange={handleChangeValues}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="cost"
        placeholder="Preço"
        className="register--input"
        onChange={handleChangeValues}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="category"
        placeholder="Categoria"
        className="register--input"
        onChange={handleChangeValues}
      />
      <button
        className="register--button"
        onClick={() => handleClickButton()}
      >
        Cadastrar
      </button>
    </div>
    {typeof listGames !== "undefined" && listGames.map((value) => {
      return <Card        
        key={value.id}
        listCard={listGames}
        setListCard={setListGames}
        id={value.id}
        name={value.name}
        cost={value.cost}
        category={value.category}
      ></Card>
    })}
  </div>);
}
export default App;
```

Comment: só passar um array sem nenhuma item, exemplo: `useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getCards").then((response) => {
      setListGames(response.data);
      callMySound();
      
    });
}, []); // aqui`

Comment: Também tentei isso, só que passando um array sem intem ele nao renderiza automaticamente o dado do banco. Somente quando desse um reload.

Comment: Primeira é isso! tem que ver essa função no Axios o que elas está fazendo, o array é necessário sim, falta verificar esse chamada! ai! eu criaria uma funçõe e chamaria ai dentro resolvendo esse problema

Comment: outros pontos: `{listGames && listGames.map((value) => {` e no estado coloque assim `const [listGames, setListGames] = useState(null);` ou `const [listGames, setListGames] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa informar ao `useEffect` um estado para que ele fique observando, e caso ele seja aterado rodar o conteudo do `useEffect`. Do jeito que está ele fica rodando infinitamente

Seria algo assim pelo que vi do seu código

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getCards").then((response) => {
      setListGames(response.data);
      callMySound();
    });
  }, [listGames]);
```